# PHP - DateTime->add not working. Says DateInterval format is wrong

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I've been struggling for a few hours on an error that I'm sure it's silly, but I can't find to solve it.

My idea is to create a DateTime of (00:00:00), in order to add to it in a loop 4:30 hours per $i.

```
$saldo_funcionario = new DateTime('00:00:00');
for ($i=0; $i<$value; $i++) {
    $tempo_dia_funcionario = new DateInterval('PT4H30I');
    $saldo_funcionario->add($tempo_dia_funcionario);
}
```

The error message is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT4H30I)' 
DateInterval->__construct('PT4H30I') #1 {main} on line 75
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: the input for new DateTime() needs to be at least a date... you are supplying only a time

Comment: The interval should be 4 hours and 30 mins?

Comment: There's no `I` modifier, only `M` both for minutes and months.

Comment: @RichardBernards DateTime will cope quite happily with just a time. http://3v4l.org/iKUtG :)

Comment: @vascowhite I learned something today... I stand corrected

Comment: @RichardBernards We are all here to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$tempo_dia_funcionario = new DateInterval('PT4H30I');
```

Should be:

```
$tempo_dia_funcionario = new DateInterval('PT4H30M');
```

Notice 'M' instead of 'I'.

http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php